# HTC 10 DRAM model

Tags: memory, mobile-phone

I wanna try to build something called a Physical Unclonable Function. It is some kind of hardware authentication feature. When the RAM is not getting refreshed it will decay and leave a pattern which is unique to the RAM in your cellphone. Therefor disabling is the first step.I have HTC 10 has lpddr4 as dram but how I can know its model: "samsung" , "micron" "jedec"  or something else?

Comment: What do you mean, "When the RAM is not getting refreshed it will decay"?  Also, "disabling is the first step" doesn't make sense...